# No inserted, deleted updated views availble

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v18 and I am trying to write a single trigger for insert delete and update.

For that, I am planning to use the inserted, deleted and updated views available.

But when I try to use them, it seems like none of the views are available. I have also checked the system views and could see the above views are not available there.

Can someone help please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of a trigger you can refer the `deleted` and `inserted` logical (conceptual) tables.

> They're structurally similar to the table on which the trigger is
> defined, that is, the table on which the user action is tried. The
> deleted and inserted tables hold the old values or new values of the
> rows that may be changed by the user action.

You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) but the point is you need to create the trigger and refer them in its body. They will be visible only there and the SSMS is clever enough to autocomplete its columns (the same as the table columns the trigger is defined on).

The tables are not DMV/system views. That's why you can find them.

Also, there is not `updated` view. If a record is deleted - its data lives in the `deleted` table and if a record is `created` its data lives in the `inserted` table. If there is an update, the record has data in both of the tables.